# MongoDB Aggregate Sum

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

```
{
    "_id":1
    "Data1": "R"
    "Data2": "A"
    "Data3": [{"TP":"1", "Vl":200},{"TP":"2", "Vl":100}, {"TP":"1", "Vl": 50} ]
}
{
    "_id":2
    "Data1": "G"
    "Data2": "A"
    "Data3": [{"TP":"1", "Vl":400}]
}
{
    "_id":3
    "Data1": "R"
    "Data2": "K"
    "Data3": [{"TP":"2", "Vl":500}, {"TP":"3", "Vl":20}]
}
```

I need sum all Vl in Data3 grouped by data1, return like:

```
[{"Data1":"R", "sum":870}, {"Data1":"G", sum:400}]
```

some like Sql:

```
Select Data1, sum(Data3.Vl) 
from Collection
Group By
Data1
```

I Try this but get sum 0 ever.

```
db.getCollection("Collection").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "Data1" : "$Data1"
                }, 
                "SUM(Data3᎐Vl)" : {
                    "$sum" : "$Data3.Vl"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "Data1" : "$_id.Data1", 
                "SUM(Data3᎐Vl)" : "$SUM(Data3᎐Vl)", 
                "_id" : NumberInt(0)
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : true
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
db.getCollection("Collection").aggregate([{$unwind: '$Data3'}, {$group : {_id : '$Data1', sum: { $sum : '$Data3.Vl'}}}])
```

You would say below, when in your aggregation query a pipeline step needs to use some temporary disk space if they exceed more than 100MB of memory. Try to filter documents as early as possible using `$match` before doing `$unwind` on whole collection.

```
{ 
        "allowDiskUse" : true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to calculate the sum of the 'Vl' present in the Data3 array. The following query can get you the expected output:

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$Data1",
            "Data1":{
                $first:"$Data1"
            },
            "sum":{
                $sum:{
                    $sum:"$Data3.Vl"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Output:

```
{ "Data1" : "G", "sum" : 400 }
{ "Data1" : "R", "sum" : 870 }
```

*The innermost $sum is summing the 'Data3.Vl' whereas the outer $sum is summing the calculated sum :)*